# Python Speed and memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Hello im pretty new in Python and i have a simple function that looks like this:

```
def normal_list(p, data, n):
  cost = 0
  cost_list = []
  list = []
  clappend=cost_list.append
  listappend=list.append
  for i in range(n):
    x = np.random.choice(data, p=p)
    if (len(list) == 0):
        listappend(x)
    else:
        for i in list:
            if i == x:
                clappend(cost)
            elif i == list[-1]:
                    listappend(x)
            cost += 1
        cost = 0
  return cost_list
```

Where p is a list of probability, data is a list of data in almost all case it will be list with numbers 1-100
I must to speed this up cause i've to use this function for n=100000 then it takes very long time and end in memory error for cost_list.
Thanks for all advice i just found my error. I messed up couse i didint break loop after finding x in my list.so Thanks again and use of generator was a good idea.

Comment: Oh, _please_, do not call your variable `list`! `list()` is a built-in list constructor.

Comment: What is the intent in words?

Comment: It seems that you have at least quadratic O(n^2) complexity here. It looks like you could reduce it to linear O(n), but honestly I don't understand what your function is supposed to be doing. And that is usually a much bigger problem than performance issues.

Comment: `i == list[-1]` is eventually true at each iteration of the outer loop. Looks like you always append `x` to `list`, unless it is the number of the current iteration. Is that true? If so, a further major optimization of your code is possible.

Comment: it should add x to the list only if in there is not variable with value x already in list.. and it count how many iterations it need to find this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If *n* is very large, consider splitting the function and changing them to [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). Using `yield` instead of return will save allot of memory by yielding results "on the fly" rather than collecting everything before returning.

   This may not be a fully functional implementation of the above with generators, but it's a start:

   ```
   def sub1(lst, x):
       cost = 0
       for e in lst:
           cost += 1
           if e == x:
               yield (cost, None)
           elif e == lst[-1]:
               yield (None, x)

   def normal_list(p, data, n):
       lst = []
       for i in range(n):
           x = np.random.choice(data, p=p)
           if len(lst) == 0:
               yield x
           else:
               for res in sub1(lst, x):
                   if res[0] is not None:
                       yield res[0]
                   else:
                       lst += res[1]
   ```
2. Although this seems more of a memory problem than a speed problem, you can try using [PyPy](https://pypy.org/) for a faster Python environment. (The first point should be sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the outer condition check. Your `list` is empty only once: before the first iteration. Why not initialize at once and skip the first iteration of the outer loop and the check altogether:

```
def normal_list(p, data, n):
    cost = 0
    cost_list = []
    _list = [np.random.choice(data, p=p)]
    #clappend=cost_list.append # Don't do this! It's confusing!
    #listappend=_list.append(x) # Don't do this! It's confusing!
    for i in range(1,n):
        ...
```